# Confusion about bitwise OR operation in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, operators

Why does Python do this:

```
100|111 = 111
1000|1001 = 1001
```

Above two examples look like bitwise OR operation

But for the below example:

```
1000|1111 = 2047
```

Why is it `2047` and not `1111`?

Comment: Because those are interpreted as integer values. Try with 1000 | 0001 and you will recive SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers. Just convert the decimal number to binary and do the | operation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're performing the operation on integers, and hence on they're corresponding binary representation. You need to convert them to binary using the `base` argument in `int`, and then perform the bitwise OR:

```
bin(int('1000', 2) | int('1111', 2))
# '0b1111'
```

Otherwise you'd get:

```
1000|1111
# 2047
```

Which corresponds to the bitwise OR between the following binary numbers (not the actual 1s and 0s of the *integer* number):

```
bin(1000)
#'0b1111101000'

bin(1111)
# '0b10001010111'

int(bin(1000), 2) | int(bin(1111), 2)
# 2047
```